# Counting degrees of freedom

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Why does a tensor with 3 indices in $n$ dimensions, such that if you swap any two of the indices gives the same value, has degree of freedom equal to $$n+2 \choose 3$$? I would have thought that it's $$n^3\over \text{#permutations=3!=6}$$...

Thanks.

Comment: @Berci: I read that the degrees of freedom of a 3-index totally symmetric tensor in $n$ dimensions is $${1\over 6}n(n+1)(n+2)$$.
Unfortunately this is all the information I have about the tensor.

Comment: Aha, what about 2-index symmetric tensors, i.e. symmetric matrices? Because of the *diagonal* we have  $\binom{n+1}2$ freedom places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the dimension of the space of degree $3$ monomials in variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. You can compute this as the sum of monomials with distinct factors $\binom{n}{3}$ plus the number of monomials with a single repeat $n(n-1)$ plus the number of monomials $x_i^3$, which is $n$. Adding these should give $\binom{n+2}{3}$. A sneakier way of getting this count is to think of choosing $3$ things from the list $x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,y_2$, with $\{x_i,y_1,y_2\}\mapsto x_i^3$, $\{x_i,x_j,y_1\}\mapsto x_i^2x_j$ if $i<j$ and $\{x_i,x_j,y_2\}\mapsto x_ix_j^2$ if $i<j$.

Indeed the number of degree $k$ monomials in $n$ variables is $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$, by a similar argument.